# Vertically centered line after the text

Tags: html, css

What I try to create is a simple line that will go *after* the text vertically centered. So far, I've come up with the following solution:

```
<h1>lorem ipsum <span></span></h1>

h1 > span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px; width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  background-color: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xqp7m2h/

[image]

The bad thing about this approach (not to mention that the line is not 100% vertically centered) is that this is a too compilcated solution for such an easy task.

What I thought about is maybe to add a line-through an invisible text within the span:

```
h1 > span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

However, I failed to make it work.

Any ideas on how to make a visible line-through with hidden text, or maybe another solution that would be simplier than what I have now?

Comment: Is your objective to just have a line displayed visually after the h1, and not really "a line-through hidden text"? If so, you could use the `:after` pseudo-element, [something like this perhaps?](https://jsfiddle.net/7xqp7m2h/2/)

Comment: @chazsolo, this was one of the options I tried, however, it is not really that simple too.

Comment: hmm... simple is pretty subjective :) With this option, you only have one element on the page, and the :after is style-able. StefanJanssen's approach is also simple but requires extra mark-up.

Comment: Also depends on how you are gonna use it. My approach can't do pixel perfect lines. But giving it another color is done with the color attribute (and thus can be inherited from the h1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a span at all.

A pseudo-element and flexbox can do that.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7xqp7m2h/)

```css
h1::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex can easily help you *(set a width if you wish to h1 or pseudo )*.

the use of a pseudo avoids the extra span in the HTML, you can apply it to any title level .

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}
h1:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>lorem ipsum </h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xqp7m2h/4/

Comment: @NenadVracar looks like SO is buggy, on edit, snippet is there, once saved, not anymore ?? jsfiddle link is efficient :)

Comment: Thanks, GCyrillus, but Paulie was first with a similar solution. I didn't think about flexbox, but it seems like a good approach! (taken that I don't need to support IE < 9).

Comment: @Deka87 no problem, just be happy to have a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/9crkt4hn/

Using `&nbsp;` as text in the span will make a space without seeing it as a space :P
As you see in the fiddle you see it works without problems.

Comment: Please select the answer that worked for you as "answer" so other people can find it :P

Comment: Stefan, this did answer my initial question. However, I had to change it, as I am also looking for other solution. The downside of the this solution is that I can't control the width of the lin without adding new &nbsp; signs, also I can't control the height of the line (stroke width).

Comment: I think the stroke width could be set with the weight of the font. You can not  do pixel perfect lines.